# Tornado - mount Bottle app

Tags: python, websocket, wsgi, tornado, bottle

How do you mount Bottle app in Tornado server?
[Here is my code](https://gist.github.com/2497341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bottle.default_app()` returns a WSGI callable:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottle_app = bottle.default_app()
    bottle_handler = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(bottle_app)
    HTTPServer(Application([(r"/ws", WSHandler),
                            (r"/css/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./css/"}),
                            (r"/js/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./js/"}),
                            (r"/img/(.*)", StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./img/"}),
                            ("/(.*)", bottle_handler)])
                         ).listen(1024)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: I already created a project on the github https://github.com/cime/bottle-tornadosocket :)